# Error with StateSpaceTransform: the rule based transformation must be of length 2

Tags: control-systems, coordinate-transformation

I would like to perform a change of variables on the following dynamics system:

```
system = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{y1'[t] == y2[t], 
y2'[t] == -theta[t]^2 y1[t] + 
  theta'[t] y2[t]/theta[t]}, {alpha1 y1[t] + alpha2 y2[t]}}, {y1[
t], y2[t]}, {}]
```

The change of variables would be: y2[t] -> theta[t] y3[t].
While I could easily see what would be the outcome by hand, I don't see why this command would not return anything with Mathematica:

```
StateSpaceTransform[system, {{y2[t] -> theta[t] y3[t]}, {y3[t] -> 
y2[t]/theta[t]}}]
```

The error I receive is meaningless in my honest point of view since:

```
Length@ {{y2[t] -> theta[t] y3[t]}, {y3[t] -> 
y2[t]/theta[t]}}
```

returns 2.

Comment: It's `Length /@` that must give {2, 2}.  It wants 2 transformations going both ways.  Since you have to put something in for a second transformation in each, how about putting `y1[t] -> y1[t]` into both of them?

Comment: Yes you're right. I added the two dummy transformations but it seams to say that the system is not a valid nonlinear state space model... I guess Mathematica doesn't like the time varying parameters

Comment: If MMA doesn't like time varying parameters, make them state variables.  Maybe it's the $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ that's confusing things.  What governs the time evolution of $\theta$ anyway?

Comment: It is unknown. I was just willing to see the pretty change of variables. It's a petty that TV systems are not treated by Mathematica. Most industrial applications are modeled as such.

Answer (score 1):

(Several points that make it too long for a comment.)

- As @LouisB points out in the comments, `StateSpaceTrasform` is expecting a transformation of dimension {2, 2}.
- The usage of `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` should be something as shown below. What you have is GIGO. (Just try `StateSpaceModel[system]`.)

  ```
  eqns = {D[y1[t], t] == y2[t], 
      D[y2[t], t] == -theta[t]^2 y1[t] + D[theta[t], t] y2[t]/theta[t]};

  NonlinearStateSpaceModel[eqns, {y1[t], y2[t], theta[t]}, {}, 
  {alpha1 y1[t] + alpha2 y2[t]}, t]
  ```
- Next, what you want as your state space is not clear. What is the initial state-space? $\{y1, y2\}$ or $\{y1, y2, theta\}$. When you invoke `StateSpaceTransform` what do you want your final state-space to be?
- And finally, the system you have is problematic. This is related to the point above. You need to have a well-defined state space for any computations to make sense.

  ```
  NDSolve[Join[eqns, {y1[0]==1,y2[0]==0,theta[0]==0.01}],{y1,y2},{t,0,1}]
  ```

  returns unevaluated with the message

  > NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {theta[t],y1[t],y2[t]}, 
  >       than equations, so the system is underdetermined.

**Update**

Convert to state-space form. To do this we need to briefly consider the time-varying parameter as constant.

```
system = With[{tempRules = {theta[t] -> theta, theta'[t] -> thetaD}},
   NonlinearStateSpaceModel[eqns /. tempRules, 
   {y1[t], y2[t]}, {}, {alpha1 y1[t] + alpha2 y2[t]}, t] /. Reverse /@ tempRules]
```

> [image]

Then perform the state-space transformation.

```
StateSpaceTransform[system, {{1, 0}, {0, theta[t]}}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Hi Suba! My initial state-space is {y1,y2} as I mentioned above, so I expect the new state space to be {y1,y3}. In my point of view theta[t] is not a state, it is a time-varying quantity making the system non-autonomous. I do not want to define it with a specific function.

Comment: Hi Mirko. Currently, when converting from a differential or difference equation the time dependent parameters need to be either a state or an input variable. You can circumvent this by temporarily assigning them to constants when the conversion to state-space form happens. Pls see my update.

Comment: The problem with this convention is that you miss the derivatives when converting: I I do the derivative of y2 I would have to see theta' y3+theta y3'. This seams to be missing with the assignment you're suggesting. I would expect from the change of variables a real Jordan form.

Comment: I see. Yes. It is a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: The fix will be in the next release. Thanks.